# Steps to download Test Scripts as attachments from Quality Center

Tags: hp-quality-center

I am aware that we can create an excel macro to connect to QC and download the test case count and details like that into excel rows. But is there a way to download the test scripts in the form of files to local desktop.

Please share some pointers for the same.

Thanks,
Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ExtendedStorage` object to download files. To get the VAPI-XP script of the test case I use this function (it's in Ruby but I hope you get the idea... `test` is an object of type Test, `local_dir` a string):

```
def download_script(test, local_dir)
  test_storage = test.ExtendedStorage
  test_storage.ClientPath = local_dir
  test_storage.Load("*.*", true)
end
```

Comment: can you please share any link that provides more details about this approach

Comment: You can consult the HP ALM Open Test Architecture API Reference, which you find in the ALM Documentation Library. Or [online](http://almhelp.saas.hp.com/ja/12.50/api_refs/ota/topic2027.html).